# "Sorry, installation of this driver failed.  Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log."

Tags: wireless, internet-connection

The story is that I've managed to install ubuntu on my windows 7 laptop and gives me the choice of which operating system I want to use every time the laptop boots up. However, I have internet on Windows 7. Yet, no internet on Ubuntu. The result I get with this problem is "Sorry, installation of this driver failed.

Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log."

What is even worse, I have to keep switching back and forth to figure out what you're responses are going to be and what attempts I've tried to get internet access to work on ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information. In addition, are you having issues with the wired or wireless connection?

Comment: I am having issues that are wireless.

Comment: Plus, it is a 64-bit operating system. My processor is Pentium(R) Dual Core CPU. Dunno if that would help.

Comment: You need to setup a wired internet connection, which you'll have to use to download and install the wireless drivers.

Comment: well...take a look at '/var/log/jockey.log' and post the output as an edit to your question ;) I suspect you tried to install the drivers via the 'additional drivers' function in system settings? problem with that is it needs to download the drivers. So as many others suggested, plug your laptop into your router (the ethernet connection should connect automatically) and then try to install the driver again

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your computer with a cable to the Internet, once that is done follow the instructions on this page to install your wireless card drivers

- [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver)

That utility will identify your card, download and install the necessary drivers for it. After that you will be able to use your wireless card.

You need an active Internet connection for the utility to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-a-common broadcom-sta-source
```

and then

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

now try to run jockey...

similarly add graphics driver repos. and then try.
this worked for me.